# Android, Changing Menu popup background color

Tags: android, android-theme

I am trying to change the background color of the `Popup` menu in the action bar.

Everything that I try its always the same black color, that is by default.

This is what I have in my `styles.xml`

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/app_navbar_background</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/app_navbar_background</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/CadetBlue</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/MediumPurple</item>
    </style>
```

And I do have the theme set in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Does anybody know what I could be doing wrong

Comment: if you are using AppCompat , use Base.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu as parent...and include both: <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/MediumPurple</item> <item name="popupBackground">@color/MediumPurple</item>

Answer (score 3):

Try using this:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/app_navbar_background</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol: `android:Widget.AppCompat.ListPopupWindow`

Comment: Tried changing it to `Base.Widget.AppCompat.ListPopupWindow` it doesn't complain, but it also doesn't change the background color.

Comment: No complaints from IDE, however the background is still black